# Writing a formula in VBA while looping through various files?

Tags: vba

I have the following code with a specific file name:

```
  BD.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=SUMIF('P:\Actuary\Cash Flow Forecast\Annual and Quarterly Budget Data\[ECMQA 2012Q1.xls]Sheet1'!$D$13:$D$234,D2,OFFSET('P:\Actuary\Cash Flow Forecast\Annual and Quarterly Budget Data\[ECMQA 2012Q1.xls]Sheet1'!$D$13:$D$234,0,MATCH(E2,'P:\Actuary\Cash Flow Forecast\Annual and Quarterly Budget Data\[ECMQA 2012Q1.xls]Sheet1'!$D$12:$R$12,0)-1))"
```

However, I'm running a loop which goes into a folder and selects all the files within it (the file above is in that folder, I was testing my code out to see if it worked for one file):

```
Dim wb As Workbook, sFile As String, sPath As String
Dim itm As Variant
Dim strFileNames  As String

sPath = "C:\Actuary\Cash Flow Forecast\Annual and Quarterly Budget Data\"

''Retrieve the current files in directory
sFile = Dir(sPath)
Do While sFile <> ""
    strFileNames = strFileNames & "," & sFile
    sFile = Dir()
Loop

''Open each file found
For Each itm In Split(strFileNames, ",")
    If itm <> "" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sPath & itm)

        ''LOTS OF CALCULATIONS, INCLUDING ABOVE CODE


    End If
Next itm
```

How would I write the first code if I don't know the file name (since it's looping through all of them)?

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub WriteFormulas()

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rNext As Range

    sPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\My Documents\Tester\"

    'Get the first file
    sFile = Dir(sPath & "*.xls")

    Do While Len(sFile) > 0
        'don't process this workbook
        If sFile <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            'set a variable to the first sheet in the file
            Set sh = Workbooks.Open(sFile).Worksheets(1)
            'find the next available cell in column A in this workbook
            Set rNext = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            'create a formula using the address with the external argument
            rNext.Formula = "=SUM(" & sh.Range("A1:A10").Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ")"
            'close the workbook
            sh.Parent.Close False
        End If
        sFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

When you close the workbook, Excel will expand the references to the full path and file name.  So while `Range("A1").Address(,,,true)` might resolve to

```
[MyBook.xls]Sheet1!A1
```

when you close MyBook.xls, it will convert to

```
'C:\Path\[MyBook.xls]Sheet1'!A1
```

Comment: First off, thank you very much for your help!  However, what would I do with the range object in `Range("A1:A10")` in the code if all I wanted was to show `[MyBook.xls]` when open or `'C:\Path\[MyBook.xls]` when closed?  I'm fixing the sheet and cells because they are always going to be the same for each file.

Comment: The thing is too that not all of my files have an .xls extenstion, they're either .xls or .xlsx so that's why I used the other code...

Comment: That's what it does now - expands the path when open and contracts when closed.  Using the range object's Address property allows Excel to build the string.  But you can build the string if you want.  Like `.Formula = "=SUMIF('" & sPATH & "[" & sFile & "]" & "Sheet1'!$D$13:$D$234,D2,OFFSET('" & sPath & "[" & sFile & "]Sheet1'!$D$13:$D$234,0,MATCH(E2,'" & sPATH & "[" & sFile & "]Sheet1'!$D$12:$R$12,0)-1))"`  Even if you do it, I'll be Excel contracts and expands it anyway.

Comment: You can use `Dir(sPath & "*.xls?")` to get both xls and xlsx.

Comment: Thanks! Building the string like you mentioned above did the trick!